# might and magic from g2a

Tags: steam

If I'll buy the game from G2A, I think I'll only get the serial number, and not the actual game.
So, where can I download the game after that?
G2A seams a lot cheaper than Steam.

Answer (score 1):

Open your steam client, and go to the library tab. At the bottom left corner of the client there should be an "Add Games" link. Clicking that opens up a prompt that walks you through adding the game.

Comment: If the game is Might and Magic X (I can't find any other M&M games (other than Heroes spin-offs) on steam), then it is very likely that they are selling a uplay key, rather than steam key.

Comment: I'm just making an assumption that he's talking about a steam-based game because he explicitly mentioned that g2a was cheaper than steam. Either way, I'd never recommend someone actually buy from them, they're a terribly shady, underhanded company. Unfortunately that's an opinion thing and not welcome as part of an answer.